# If I times a float by it's multiple (1.3 * 10) to put it into an integer, is it more accurate than staying with the float in computation?

Tags: javascript, numbers, floating-accuracy

OK OK.  I know there's libraries out there.  I know there's quite a few posts on this subject of float accuracy but the ones I've run into haven't really answered the question for me.  Being the inquisitive individual that I am, I want a thorough answer.

**TLDR;**

Is "converting" a float to an integer by it's multiple more accurate as a way of computing very large floats in JavaScript rather than by just the floats?  Meaning: in an equation `1.3e-12 * 1.4`, if I `(1.3e-12 * 10000000000000) * (1.4 * 10000000000000) / 10000000000000`, is it more accurate?

**LONGER**

I want to know if I take a number say: 1.3e-11 and `~~(1.3 * Math.pow(11, 10))`, is the not operator `~~`, or any bitwise operator that will truncate 64bit floats, even needed to ensure that a float goes to an integer?  If the numbers are stored in javascript as floats anyway, it doesn't appear to me that it's really needed.  Also is "converting" floats to integers in JavaScript safe and supremely accurate?  If I work with large decimals in this way, it DOES appear to heighten output accuracy.

For instance:

`144 * 0.3048 / 0.0254`

the conversion from 144 sqft to inches yields 1728.000000000002.  However:

```
var a, b, c, p = 4;
a = 144 * Math.pow(10, p);
b = 0.3048 * Math.pow(10, p);
c = 0.0254 * Math.pow(10, p);
console.log((a * b / c) / Math.pow(10, p));
```

Yields exactly 1728.

Another question I have is: Does stored very long computed floats that have not been converted to larger ints less accurate in a series of computations?

Comment: `* 10000000000000` is by no means "integer conversion". Btw, your first example is invalid, as you'd need to divide twice after the multiplication.

Comment: Floats do have 53 bits for accurate integers, if you use bitwise operators you have only 31.

Comment: @Bergi - yeah that's what I was getting, specifically the >> shift operators.  I like the obscurity but for very large numbers, it probably isn't best. - The first example I think is fine.  Times each part of the equation by the same number and then divide by that number.

Comment: "conversion from 144 sqft to inches" ??? Normally converting a [dimension]^2 to a [dimension] indicates an error in a formula. If accuracy to 16 [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) is important, you should evaluate the error bounds for every stage of the calculation. Otherwise, just use rounding to a sensible number of significant figures to *display* the final value. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may be interesting to you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Well the conversion is into meters and then divided by the metric conversion of the new imperial unit.  So there's .3048 meters in a foot, and .0254 meters in an inch.  Yeah I've skimmed over that reading before.  I should probably spend a good couple evenings just reading it through thoroughly.

Comment: @DataHerder You might want to add [Dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) to your reading list. An inch is *defined* as 0.0254 m, so a square inch is 0.00064516 square meters.

Comment: Yikes, that's my misstep.  I need to get the conversion before applying the area formula.  My bad.